# Anyone with knowledge in org.web3j.abi.Type Decoder?

Tags: web3j, abi, java, decoding

I am trying to decode a String with this code that I found but I have not been able to do it.

```java
String to = inputdata.substring(10, 74);
String value = inputdata.substring(74, 138);

Method refMethod = TypeDecoder.class.getDeclaredMethod("decode", String.class, int.class, Class.class);
refMethod.setAccessible(true);

String cadena = (String) refMethod.invoke(null, to, 0, String.class);
System.out.println(cadena);
Uint256 amount = (Uint256) refMethod.invoke(null, value, 0, Uint256.class);
System.out.println(amount.getValue());
```

I can get uint256 but not the string

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to decode `erc20 transfer` method.

You must use the object `org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address` rather than `String.class`.

Example:

```java
final Address address = (Address) refMethod.invoke( null, to, 0, Address.class);
System.out.println(address.toString());
```

and `address.toString()`  is the real recipient of the ERC20 transaction.